# Problems with TreeView and Prism-5

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-5

I'm having quite a lot of problems trying to build a TreeView using Prism and MVVM. I have my application divided in Regions one of this regions have a module with a TreeView and another region has as module a Ribbon where some kind of projects can be created and configured. Those regions are communicated using prism and that works perfectly. So when a project is created in the "Ribbon Module", the "TreeView Module" gets it and here is where the problem comes.

The ViewModel of the "TreeView Module" has an ObservableCollection where all project should be added. The name of the project and other properties of this class should be showed in the TreeView.

```
public class Project : BindableBase
{
    private List<DataSet> _DataSetList;
    private string _projectName;

    public Project()
    {
        DataSetList = new List<DataSet>();
        ProjectName = "";
    }

    public Project(string projectName, List<DataSet> dataSets)
    {
        ProjectName = projectName;
        DataSetList = dataSets;
    }

    public string ProjectName
    {
        get { return _projectName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this._projectName, value); }
    }
    public List<DataSet> DataSetList
    {
        get { return _DataSetList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this._DataSetList, value); }
    }

    public bool CheckForLoadedDataSets() 
    {
        foreach (DataSet ds in DataSetList) 
        {
            if(ds.Status != DataSet.DataSetStatus.Loaded)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is what a DataSet is

```
public class DataSet : BindableBase
{
    public enum DataSetStatus
    {
        Loaded,
        Stopped,
        Unloaded,
        Empty,
        LoadingData,
        CorruptData,
    };

    private string _dataSetSource;
    private DataSetStatus _status;

    public DataSet(string name, string sourceName, List<Injector> injertors)
    {
        DataSetName = name;
        DataSetSource = sourceName;
        Injectors = injertors;
        Status = DataSetStatus.Empty;
    }

    public DataSet(string name, string sourceName)
    {
        DataSetName = name;
        DataSetSource = sourceName;
        Injectors = new List<Injector>();
        Status = DataSetStatus.Empty;
    }

    public DataSet(string sourceName)
    {
        DataSetName = "";
        DataSetSource = sourceName;
        Injectors = new List<Injector>();
        Status = DataSetStatus.Empty;
    }

    public string DataSetName { get; set; }
    public string DataSetSource { get { return _dataSetSource; } set { SetProperty(ref this._dataSetSource, value); } }
    public List<Injector> Injectors { get; set; }
    public DataSetStatus Status { get { return _status;} set{ SetProperty(ref this._status,value);} }
}
```

This is the TreeViewViewModel

```
class TreeProjectManagerViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private ObservableCollection<Project> _projectCollection;        

    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
    {
        get { return this._projectCollection; }
        set 
        {
            SetProperty(ref this._projectCollection, value); 
        }
    }

    public TreeProjectManagerViewModel() 
    {
        Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();                        
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checking parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="navigationContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        if (navigationContext.Parameters["ProjectObject"] != null) 
        {
            return true;
        }                      
        return false;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Getting information from other module 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="navigationContext"></param>
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        Project p = (Project)navigationContext.Parameters["ProjectObject"];            
        Projects.Add(p);
    }
}
```

And here the code in the View

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">            
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProjectName}"/>                    
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

With this I'm able to get the name of the Project in my TreeView but for example, an here my questions:

1.- how can I get a second hierarchy of TreeNodes with the name of each DataSet?

2.- how can I manage the events in my TreeView?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <ie:CallMethodAction MethodName="OnTreeviewLoaded" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Project}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataSetList}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProjectName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:DataSet}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataSetName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

you also need to add :

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

into your xaml and create the event handler in your view model

Comment: I could not do a copy/paste of your answer but it was useful to get some inspiration. First of all I'm getting problems adding

`code` 
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
`code`

Comment: they depends on "Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll"   if they are not released with prism, check into your blend folder.